# TYPE keyword . Help me in interpreting this code in plsql?

Tags: oracle, plsql, user-defined-types

```
 TYPE datatype_type
IS
  TABLE OF datatype%ROWTYPE
     INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

datatype_bulk datatype_type;
```

I have googled for TYPE keyword but was't able to get answer except for create object types . 
Please see if anyone can explain this !

Comment: The code you posted is an example of [defining a PL/SQL collection type](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/collections.htm#i20383).  Share and enjoy.

Comment: I think the problem here is one of Google Fu.  If you had included "INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER" in your search you would immediately have found some helpful documentation.

Comment: Please read this answer to another SO question

Comment: possible duplicate of [Purpose of using collections in oracle and different between the collections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14934514/purpose-of-using-collections-in-oracle-and-different-between-the-collections)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TYPE is used for user-defined types within PLSQL packages. Outside the plsql package the statement is CREATE TYPE.

Here's some more information about user-defined types within packages: [link](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.plsql.doc/doc/c0053919.html)