# Pass Multiple information on a procedure call

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to pass multiple product keys to a procedure, like `product 1,2,5,7`

I'm calling the procedure the following way:

```
call procedure_test('emp1',(1,2,5,7));
```

passed with the following `where` condition:

```
i:= (1,2,5,7)
 where a.products in (i)
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2885575/1707353), is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: PL/SQL doesn't support anonymous array types - they have to be named, which means either a standalone `create or replace type xyz as table of number;` or else a PL/SQL declaration in a package spec, like `type xyz is table of number;` (or one of the other collection types - there are [three](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14934514/230471)).

Comment: Which of those collection types can be used in a `where` clause depends on the version of Oracle you are using, I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I love a good associative array, here is my take (even though what jeff6times7 suggested is just as good) :

```
DECLARE
   -- Declare the associative array type
   TYPE typTabProductID IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

   -- Array variable, used for test only
   tableTest typTabProductID;

   -- Procedure eating a parameter of array type
   PROCEDURE myProc(tabProductID typTabProductID) IS
   BEGIN
      FOR i IN 1 .. tabProductID.COUNT LOOP
         dbms_output.put_line(tabProductID(i));
      END LOOP;
   END;
BEGIN
   -- Fill the array variable
   tableTest(1) := 5;
   tableTest(2) := 8;
   tableTest(3) := 11;

   -- call the procedure
   myProc(tableTest);
END;
```

Comment: A nested table is likely to be more useful than an associative array, especially if the OP wants to use the passed values in a SQL statement, which it appears they do.